# How to find out the current SGA memory distribution?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I get the **current** SGA memory distribution on Oracle 10G?

Something like this:

```
AME                                SIZE_MB RES
-------------------------------- ---------- ---
Maximum SGA Size                        396 No
Shared Pool Size                        320 Yes
Startup overhead in Shared Pool          32 No
Streams Pool Size                        32 Yes
Java Pool Size                           24 Yes
Buffer Cache Size                        16 Yes
Granule Size                              4 No
Redo Buffers                           2,79 No
Fixed SGA Size                         1,21 No
Free SGA Memory Available                 0
Large Pool Size                           0 Yes
```

I found this table at [Marko Sutic's Oracle Blog](http://msutic.blogspot.com/2009/06/sga-sizing-and-asmm.html), but there is no query that provides that kind of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `select * from v$sgainfo ;`

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect as sysdba, you can display hidden parameters with the following query.

```
   MEG    GIG PARAMETER                           DESCRIPTION
------ ------ ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    .0     .0 __large_pool_size                   Actual size in bytes of large pool
    .0     .0 __streams_pool_size                 Actual size in bytes of streams pool
    .0     .0 __shared_io_pool_size               Actual size of shared IO pool
 128.0     .1 __java_pool_size                    Actual size in bytes of java pool
 512.0     .5 db_recycle_cache_size               Size of RECYCLE buffer pool for standard block size buffers
2336.0    2.3 __shared_pool_size                  Actual size in bytes of shared pool
3072.0    3.0 db_keep_cache_size                  Size of KEEP buffer pool for standard block size buffers
3808.0    3.7 __db_cache_size                     Actual size of DEFAULT buffer pool for standard block size buffer
6240.0    6.1 __sga_target                        Actual size of SGA
8192.0    8.0 __pga_aggregate_target              Current target size for the aggregate PGA memory consumed
```

The query looks like the following:

```
SYS AS SYSDBA> SELECT i.instance_name instance,
  2  -- b.ksppstvl "Session_Value",
  3  c.ksppstvl value,c.ksppstvl/1024/1024 meg,c.ksppstvl/1024/1024/1024 gig,
  4  -- above is instance_value
  5  a.ksppinm "PARAMETER",KSPPDESC "DESCRIPTION"
  6  FROM
  7  x$ksppi a,
  8  x$ksppcv b,
  9  x$ksppsv c,
 10  v$instance i
 11  WHERE
 12  a.indx = b.indx
 13  AND
 14  a.indx = c.indx
 15  AND
 16  (a.ksppinm LIKE '/_/_%' escape '/' or a.ksppinm LIKE 'db_keep_cache_size' or a.ksppinm LIKE 'db_recycle_cache_size')
 17  and a.ksppinm not in ('__oracle_base')
 18  and c.ksppstvl not in ('TRUE','FALSE')
 19  order by 3
 20  /
```